# When does my one-to-one subscription expire?

Tags: accounts

I recently ordered a new MacBook Pro and a One to One membership online. I got an email saying that my MBP will arrive in "3 or 4 weeks". I also got an email saying "Thank you for joining One to One. Please activate your membership online".

Does my one-to-one membership expire 12 months from receipt of this email or 12 months after I activate it?

In other words, if I activate it now, I can imagine it will expire 11 months after I receive my MacBook Pro. But if I activate one-to-one when my MacBook Pro arrives, will I have wasted a month of One to One?

Comment: Stop by the Apple Store you plan on using your One to One membership at and ask. I think it's likely that the year will be counted starting at activation date, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a reply from rep at Apple Store, who agrees with CajunLuke above.

```
About the One to One, do not activate your new One to One until you receive your computer.
So that You do not lose those  one month.
One to one starts when you activate that code online.
```

I'm in Japan which explains why the English ain't right.